# Kotlin Coroutines stop executing after first Flow.collect()

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

In the following code block, I would expect that all 3 methods are called:

- flowMethodA
- flowMethodB
- doSomethingElse

```
suspend fun setDefaults() {

    coroutineScope { 
        launch {
            flowMethodA().collect()
        }
    }

    coroutineScope { 
        launch {
            flowMethodB().collect()
        }
    }

    doSomethingElse()
}
```

For some reason, only flowMethodA is executed. Why is that and how can I collect more than one flow after another in a single method?

Comment: Do you want to call these in sequence or in parallel? If `flowMethodA` is an infinite flow, it will be impossible for this `setDefaults` function to ever return, because the `collect()` call on the flow will never return.

Comment: In this example I actually dont care if they in seuqence or Not. The flow methods are network calls that eventually are done. How would I "return" them?

Comment: A network call that is made, finishes, and returns something shouldn't be a flow in the first place. If you have a single thing to return, you should use a suspend function or a Deferred. Flows are for a stream of (usually changing/evolving) data. There are not a lot of use cases for *finite* flows--they tend to be stuff like countdowns, sometimes a series of UI states, or large amounts of data being processed in chunks. A Flow doesn't return one thing...it's conceptually a series of things.

Comment: The series of things in this case is the status and result of the network call or database fetch (loading, success, error). Google for "networkBoundResource" for more details. My understanding is that by using the terminal operator `collect()` whatever is behind `methodA` is executed while ignoring emissions AND that the code after the `collect()` statement will then be executed. Would it work like this when using the `last()` operator?
 I basically just want to trigger `methodA` and `methodB`, it would be best to let them execute in parallel and wihtout waiting for the result.

Comment: Ok, that’s a fine use, but then what are you wanting to return from this method? You will have a series of states in two different flows. `last()` and `collect()` are the same except that `last()` will return the final item in the flow. If you want them to run in parallel, put both launch calls in the same `coroutineScope` block, as mentioned in the answer below. If you want `doSomethingElse()` to also run in parallel, it should also be moved into the same block with the others.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Putting all calls into the same scope worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A coroutineScope will suspend until all child coroutines have finished before it will continue executing. You will need to call your functions in the same coroutineScope if you want them to execute concurrently.

For example like this:

```kotlin
suspend fun setDefaults() {
    coroutineScope { 
        launch {
            flowMethodA().collect()
        }

        launch {
            flowMethodB().collect()
        }

        doSomethingElse()
    }
}
```